# Why does rhandsontable dropdown not work with a limted number of items in a objects?

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

I have adapted scripts from https://github.com/jrowen/rhandsontable/tree/master/inst/examples/rhandsontable_output to learn programming shiny apps.
There you can find the ui.R file too. My server.R file reads as follows:

```
library(rhandsontable)

#articels.<-read.csv2("/home/rupert/invoiceapp/R/test2/articels.csv",sep=";")

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  # this caching step is no longer necessary
  # it was left as an example
  values = reactiveValues()
  data = reactive({
    if (!is.null(input$hot)) {
      DF = hot_to_r(input$hot)
    } else {
      if (is.null(values[["DF"]]))
        DF = data.frame(Article=letters[1:2],Price=LETTERS[1:2],stringsAsFactors = F)
     
      else
        DF = values[["DF"]]
    }
    
    values[["DF"]] = DF
    DF
  })
  
  output$hot <- renderRHandsontable({
    DF = data()
    if (!is.null(DF))#useTypes =as.logical(input$useType)
    rhandsontable(DF ,rowHeaders = NULL)%>%
    hot_col(col = "Price", type = "dropdown", source = LETTERS)%>%
    hot_col(col = "Article", type = "dropdown", source = letters)
  })    
})
```

In case I define a data.frame with only a limited numbers of items of an object, the drop down function is not available anymore  (LETTERS[1:2] instead of LETTERS).
The wanted result is a table with only a few rows in which I can choose any item of any R object.

Comment: I think the dropdown is cutoff by the small table. You could add `overflow = "visible"` such as `rhandsontable(DF, rowHeaders = NULL, overflow = "visible")` - does that give you the desired effect?

Comment: Yes after I added the argument overflow = "visible" I could choose all items of a R object in the hot_col type "dropdown" .  Since I'am working on my private invoice report script I need only less rows in my table but more items in the dropdown.